# Quick assist with finding Javascript variable (PollDaddy hash)

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

I'm working on finding a variable for a PollDaddy poll. The [API](http://support.polldaddy.com/api/) says that the hash is attributed to the variable `PDV_h[PollID]` (check "Voting" part of API). I've been looking all around this poll [here](http://polldaddy.com/poll/5547018/) but can't seem to find it. Can anyone help me figure out the hash and tell me how you were able to find it?

Comment: how did you manage to generate the hash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash doesn't seem to be used in the link you gave me [here](http://polldaddy.com/poll/5547018/).

But on what I assume is your site, [here](http://102jamzorlando.radio.com/2011/09/30/last-school-standing-round-six/), there's a variable `PDV_h5547018`, which gives you the hash you need to make the request.

This is what I got back, but this will be invalidated, of course:

```
PDV_n0='f5a9a0cf08b733a0e1738e271c9303d6';PD_vote0(0);
```

I would track down where it was made but there are so many script references. I assume you are using a script request from them, which is why they say it's in the JavaScript.

Comment: May I ask where/how you found the variable? I was trying to go through the javascript files trying to find "PDV" but that didn't work and I know that you know what you're doing. That's what I was having trouble with :P

Comment: i used the chrome debug tools and it auto completed the var when i wrote PDV

Comment: that is the console i used btw

Comment: Thanks Megakorre! I'm looking around in the Chrome console (after right-clicking and inspecting element, then click on "Console") and I'm able to find the PDV variable, but I'm trying to find the hash attributed to it (still don't know how :P). Basically, I'm trying to generate a URL where the Hash itself is generated, like http://polldaddy.com/n/b8dfecd3934003315002e5a320a6fada/5274393?1311681535295 or http://polldaddy.com/n/d738e1bae08018806dc6b4752f83e057/5379044?1313898553420. The URL is formed like this http://polldaddy.com/n/[hash]/[poll_id]?[cache_buster].